# Use of dirac delta to represent a instantaneous product in a ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dirac-delta

In order to represent a discrete instantaneous displacement of $A$ at time $t_0$ in a differential equation I've been taught to write:
$$
f'(t) = A \delta(t-t_0)
$$

I was wondering how to represent a instantaneous product for a factor $A$ at the time $t_0$ in order to describe a situation like:
$$
f(t_0^+) = A f(t_0^-)
$$

With some naive reasoning I reached the conclusion it should be something like:
$$
f'(t) = \ln (A)\delta(t-t_0)f(t)
$$

How can I prove this in a almost rigorously way?

Comment: $f'(t_0)=\delta(t-t_0)[(A-1)f(t_0^-)]$. There is not much else you can do, there is not a "multiplicative" analogue of the Dirac delta in distribution theory.

Answer (score 0):

Does the representation really matter? From what I see, you deal with non-smooth ODEs. There are a bunch of ways to deal with those. I am not familiar with most of the ways, but there is a formulation in terms of complentarity that can work for that. Otherwise, if you want to solve that, I would suggest to check event capturing schemes.